# Paying for U.S. created Azure account with Polish credit card after relocation to Poland

Tags: azure

I created Azure account back when I lived in the States but now I live in Poland and my Azure account is locked to U.S. address only. So is there a way to pay with Polish credit card???

I know you cannot delete Azure account or unlink it from Microsoft account.

I'm doing this primarily because I don't want to use different Microsoft account than my Primary Email.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support / billing question, and needs to be addressed with customer support.

Comment: Unfortunately questions around paying for cloud services are off-topic. I suggest opening a billing support ticket with Azure to discuss this further.